# Finding package OpenCV with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2012, cmake

I've done as follows:

I have set OpenCV_DIR variable to my build path set to $(OPENCV_ROOT)/build/x86/vc11/lib.

In my CMakeLists.txt I call find_package function:

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

Some variables connected to OpenCV should be set, but they are set incorrectly. Ex. OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS should be set to

```
$(OPENCV_ROOT)/build/include
```

or

```
$(OPENCV_ROOT)/include
```

but instead of it it's set to

```
$(OPENCV_ROOT)/build/x86/vc11/lib/include;$(OPENCV_ROOT)/x86/vc11/lib/include/opencv
```

What to do to have the right paths?

Answer (score 0):

I had built OpenCV from source to make sure that all the variables and options were set correctly.. For the purpose of explanation, let's say your **CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX** is set to **C:/opencv/**.. This is where your **OpenCV_DIR** variable should point to..

To your system environment path, add **C:/opencv/bin/** (just so that all login instances from your computer have access to it and also makes it easier for VS to recognize it later on, in my experience) to the **PATH** variable.. Make sure you build both debug and release version of the projects and build the **INSTALL** project for both..

Hope this helps.

Side note: For easy path editing, I use a freeware called [**RapidEE**](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download)

Answer (score 0):

I was recently fighting with compilation of OpenCV to get minimal module necessary and then automatically including this in my project. I ended up using it the following way:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED PATHS <path to the install dir>) 
target_link_directories(<target> PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_LIB_DIRS}
    )
target_link_libraries(<target> 
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    )
target_include_directories(<target> PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
```

Using cmake 3.16
OpenCV 4.x